# What is this fold/scan like concept on streams called?

Tags: haskell, stream, fold

We have this type of `StreamTransformer` defined as follows:

```
newtype StreamTransformer input output = StreamTransformer
  { runStreamTransformer :: input -> (output, StreamTransformer input output)
  }
```

The following function which looks like a scan/fold seems very useful

```
scan :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> StreamTransformer a b
scan op init = StreamTransformer $ \i -> (init, scan op (i `op` init))
```

Is there a name for this `scan`? Can it be expressed/understood as some kind of catamorphism/anamorphism?

Comment: Your `scan` function looks to me like `scanl`, adapted to a different definition of lists.

Comment: if you can represent it as a `fold` function may be you can find its relation to catamorphism.